# how to pass checkbox value to javascript function

Tags: javascript, php

my code is :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="area" id="area" value="0">Some Text1</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="area" id="area" value="80">Some Text2</input>
```

and javascript code is

```
function calc(){var textValue1 = document.getElementById('quantity').value;
var textValue2 = document.getElementById('area').value;
document.getElementById('cost').value = textValue1 * textValue2 ; }
```

but it isn't working.

Comment: Where's your PHP code?

Comment: append proper html code

Comment: @Niger : Your HTML of checkbox has the same id in both. It should be different for both the checkbox.

Comment: need to use diifernt ids for insertion not same

Comment: 1. 2 elements have the same id. 2. You don't have an element having a 'quantity' id value based on what you showed us. 3. Make sure you also have an element having an id of 'cost'

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```js
valueChange = function(item){
 alert(item.value);
}
```

```html
<form name="form1" method="post" action=" insert_data.php">
    Delivery Location
    <input onChange="valueChange(this)" type="checkbox" name="area" id="area" value="0">Inside city </input>
    <input onChange="valueChange(this)" type="checkbox" name="area" id="area" value="80">Outside city </input>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample example by using JQuery...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).ready(function() {

            $( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
                $('input[name="vehicle"]:checked').each(function() {
                    console.log(this.value);
                });

                return false;
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id='target' action="/action_page.php">
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked> I have a car<br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `id` attributes should be unique. In your case you have 2 elements with `id="area"` which confuses the `document.getElementById()` method. You can use a selector query to achieve what you want. There's not need for additional libraries such as jQuery.

Here's a working example:

```js
function calculate () {
  var selected = document.querySelector('[name="area"]:checked')
  
  if (!selected) {
    alert('Please select a value')
    return 
  }
  
  var quantity = 5 // you can get this from a different place
  
  alert('Final value: ' + selected.value * quantity)
 
}


document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', calculate)
```

```html
<form name="form1" method="post" action=" insert_data.php">
    Delivery Location
    <input type="checkbox" name="area" id="inside" value="0">Inside city </input>
    <input type="checkbox" name="area" id="outside" value="80">Outside city </input>
    <button id="submit">Calculate</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below JS code in console. you can use it as per the events u want

```
var checkedValue = null; 
var inputElements = document.getElementsByName('area');
for(var i=0; inputElements[i]; ++i){
      if(inputElements[i].checked){
           checkedValue = inputElements[i].value;
           break;
      }
}
```